# I am trying to stream a .ogg audio from one computer to another over rtp and play it using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, audio-streaming, rtp, pulseaudio

On the sender side, I have given following commands:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp
pactl load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor
pactl set-default-sink rtp

gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/Music/SomeSong.ogg
```

On the receiver side, I gave following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://<sender's ip>:5000
```

I get following error on the receiver side after above command:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://127.0.0.1:5000
**ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source: Could not open resource for reading and writing.**
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(6183): gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstRTSPSrc:source:
Failed to connect. (Generic error)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Could any one please help me out to resolve this issue and tell me where i am wrong? How to resolve this error?

Note: giving command:    pactl load-module module-rtp-recv   at receiver side starts playing the audio. **But** I want to play it using gstreamer and not directly from pulse audio. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I am not familiar with those pulseaudio modules, but why cant you just do it all in gstreamer? You can use uridecodebin, rtptheorapay, udpsink and you are done..